# How do I divide the sum with 2 after a loop

Tags: javascript, json

How do I divide the sum with 2 after a loop, so I get the value 38? I want to print out the answer in an alert box.

My Javascript code:

```
var nums = ['1','75'];
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){

    sum += parseInt(nums[i]);

}

alert(sum);
```

Or if I have the values 1, 2, 3, 4, I want to get the `sum` (in this case `10`) in the loop and divide it with `2` and print out it in an alert box.

Comment: Everytime there will be two elements in the array?

Comment: do you want to get an average?

Comment: Just before alert(), add -> sum /= 2

Comment: For example if i use the value 1, 2, 3, 4, i want to get the sum (in this case 10)  in loop and divide it with 2. Print out it in alert box!

Comment: @Sebastian so it is not the average you are looking for. This is an important information that should be added to the question and not as a comment, as of that I edited your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

```
//variable declaration and loop above
alert(sum/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide by 2 then...

```
var nums = ['1','75'];
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(nums[i]);
}
sum /= 2;
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nums = ['1','75'];


let sumDiv2 = (nums)=> {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){

      sum += Number(nums[i]);

  }
  
  return sum
}

alert(sumDiv2(nums)/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var nums = ['1','75'];
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){

    sum += parseInt(nums[i]);

}

alert(sum/2);
```

This isn't complex to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Using array `reduce` method you can do like below

```js
var arr = ["1", "67"];

var divide = arr.reduce(function (acc, ele) {
  return acc += +ele; // To convert element from string to array use +
}, 0) / 2;

console.log(divide);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on 1 line.

```js
var nums = ['1','2', '3', '4'];

var result = nums.reduce((el, acc) => parseInt(el) + parseInt(acc), 0) / 2;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = ['1','75'];
var sum = 0;

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){

    sum += parseInt(nums[i]);

}

alert(sum/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without any loop. Short, simple and stylish:

```
var arr=['1', '75'],
    sum_2=arr.reduce(function(a,b){return a*1+b*1;},0)/2;

alert(sum_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(['1','2'].reduce((p,c) => +p + +c, 0) / 2)
//                            ^ ^     ^    ^   ^ 
//                            | |     |    |   |
//          "p" as "previous"_| |     |____|   |_first "p" value
//                              |     |    
//             "c" as "current"_|     |_convert strings to integers
```

Run the snippet; what happens:

1. `.reduce()` starts on the `['1','2']`
2. In the first call to the inner function (`(p,c) => +p + +c`) the value of `p`(revious) is `0`, as the second argument passed to the `.reduce()`, and value of the `c`(urrent) is `'1'`, the first array element; the `0 + +'1'` executes, resulting in `1`
3. In the second call to the inner function the value of `p` is `1` - from previous execution, and the value of `c` is `'2'`; the `1 + +'2'` executes, resulting in `3`
4. As here are no more items in the array, the final result of `.reduce()` call gives as `3`, which is then divided by `2` in `3 / 2`, resulting in `1.5`

Unary operator `+` preceding string (`+'1'`, '+'2'`) converts the string into integers.

Answer (score -1):

You could divide the sum by `2`.

BTW, while you have already integer values as strings, you could use an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for a conversion to number.

```
sum += +nums[i];
//     ^
```

```js
var nums = ['1', '75'],
    sum = 0,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += +nums[i];
}

alert(sum / 2);
```

Comment: Can you please also give answer using best array method? because I have seen so many interesting answers posted by you, but this is very simple answer :-)